# Analyzing C++ crash developed in .NET 2010

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have written C++ program in Visual Studio .NET 2010. Assume I have written a program name "BubbyProgram" When I am executing this binaray BunnyProgram.exe. This program is crashing and I have crash file generated as

C__Program Files (x86)BubbyProgram.exe_3952_2012-10-10 13_28_52.519

How can I analyze this crash file to see where the error?

Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Let it rip in the VS debugger and wait for the exception. If all goes well you won't have to find it; it will find you.

Answer (score 0):

you can try windbg to debug the crash file.

Answer (score 0):

If the file you're looking at is a crash dump or a minidump (typically with a `*.dmp` or `*.mdmp` file extension), you can just open it up in Visual Studio and start debugging it.  Right-click it in Explorer, select "Open with...", and select Visual Studio.  Then, press F5 to start debugging it.

Visual Studio will then show you the exception that occurred (usually an access violation), the instruction where it occurred, the surrounding code, and the stack trace, depending on how much information is in the dump file.  If you have the right symbol files (`*.pdb`), it should show you the original source code location where the crash occurred; if not, you might have to tell it where to find the symbol files and/or source code, if it was compiled on a different machine.

You can also use other debuggers such as WinDbg if you want.